# Android app does not connect to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing android app using Firebase GMS service.
I tried to follow their tutorials, i made project as they said, downloaded the json files.

But when I tried to connect my app to Firebase. They show me the error

> Could not parse the Android Application Module`s Gradle config. Resolve gardle build issuse and/or resync.

[image]

However I think my grade scripts are perfect ( I'll write them bottom of the page)

[image]

This is my grade build console

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage980Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon980Library
:app:prepareComTsengvnTypekit100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\AJH322\AndroidStudioProjects\hanyang\app\src\debug\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 14.678 secs
```

and this is my gradle script (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ajh322.hanyang"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ajh322.hanyang"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

does anybody know how can I connect to Firebase with my app? 
please save my life... thanks

+ i updated my sdk tools as people said
still not works.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the gzips in your project might be the culprits. Search it up within your project folder and delete them, let gradle re-sync it for you.

Possible alternative solutions:
https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/issues/13
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/159

Comment: i thought those warnings has nothing about the firebase anyway thanks again

Comment: @AJH  what is `gzips`  I have the same issue and can not solve it?

Comment: @Nicholas what is gzips?

Comment: @FelipeCastilhos File that carry the .gz extension.

Comment: how to find and delete them?

Comment: For anyone who still face the problem, I removed .gradle and .idea from the project files then clean, build and run the app.

Comment: i am facing the same issue in my case I need to replace fabric with firebase and I have follow all steps which mention in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=1&platform=android) still facing the same issue please share your suggestion .

Answer (score 39):

I had the exact same issue. I built successfully but got the same message when hitting the 'Connect to Firebase' button via Assistant.

It turned out that I had a warning that I had to fix to get it to work.

"Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html"

I just had to replace my 'compile's with 'api' and then it worked. I'd suggest looking into fixing warnings if you have any even though your build is successful.

Comment: Thank you! In my case I had to use "implementation" instead of "compile".

Comment: its work for me this line   //jackOptions {enabled true}

Answer (score 18):

I tried a lot of ways, but the simplest way is updated `com.google.gms:google-services` from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that your app/build.gradle doesn't have obsolete dependencies and declaration. Mine the problem was with using

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

instead of

```
buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Go to the app build.gradle file. Replace 'compile' with 'api'. Then, sync your project. The warning should go away. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you need to resolve all the gradle build issues. 
Go to the gradle console (usually located in the bottom right of the IDE) and check for them errors/warnings. Once your build succeeds without errors the connection to firebase should work.

Answer (score 4):

I recently update to Android studio 4.0 and got into this error. I was still using the obsolete way to add the databinding . Changing it to the updated way to use the data binding resolved my issue. Below is the code :

```
buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding :
        // viewBinding = true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In build.gradle file replace 'compile' with 'implementation' and sync project.

Answer (score 3):

First Method:-
Just ***REMOVE*** jcenter() because this repository is going to shut down soon so this will create issue while connecting with firebase

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
```

Second Method:-
Temporary remove

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

in build.gradle(module) and

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

from build.gradle(project)

Answer (score 2):

I had some other error in build.gradle file. After commenting out below line, it started working :

```
dexOptions
            {
                //incremental false
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was shown this warning:

```
API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()
```

because of that I could not connect to firebase.

caused from gms services 4.3.0. So i had to change it to:

com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

I have found this by running:

gradlew sync -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true

in terminal. Go to view -> tool windows -> Terminal in Android Studio.
Gms services will probably fix this in the future versions.

Comment: Thanks Nurseyit - I had the same warning and also changed this in the Project build.gradle file from 4.3.0:

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Answer (score 1):

Watch out if you are using:

> android.enableR8 = true

Just remove it for the moment. That was the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone having this issue, I have solved it this way:
Android Studio - 3.4.2

Fix all the warning in the "Build" window.
Change compile to "implementation" and "testImplementation", "androidTestImplementation"etc

Remove this line app build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line if you are working with `databinding` from gradle.properties

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Comment: where is this line? I have viewBinding {enabled = true} deleting this line dind't solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

in build.gradle (Module.app)
if you use view binding, comment it temporarily, then sync!

```
/*
viewBinding {
   enabled = true
}
*/
```

then connect to firebase. I use AS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! When I used Android Studio Firebase assistant and clicked 'Connect to Firebase' button, I had the same issue. 
The solution is simple: forget the assistant (obviously, there is some bug in it), just follow the instruction of manually integrating the Firebase project into your Android Studio project (create the project in the Firebase console, download the json file and put it inside the 'app' folder etc.)
Don't forget to make sure all the Firebase dependencies are of the same version (e.g. 11.8.0). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is, to replace all "compile 'com.google...." to "implementation 'com.google..."

Answer (score 0):

In the Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This helped me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This answer is too minimal and unclear. Are you saying the plugin should be removed from the file? Regards.

Comment: @Elletlar you have to add this line. But in my case it dindn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to remove error and warning from build.gradle.

which you **can easily find at: Build Tab(at bottom)->Sync Tab-> Here you can find the issue**

Answer (score 0):

in my case in my manifest remove node

```
 <application
        android:name=".controller.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:node="replace"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

remove this line

```
 tools:node="replace"
```

and replace with this

```
tools:replace="allowBackup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line if you are working with databinding from gradle.properties

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Already the databinding is enabled in the app gradle file

Comment: where is this line? I have viewBinding {enabled = true} deleting this line dind't solved this problem

Comment: you have to add this line in gradle.properties file

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved it by updating the sha-1 code to firebase console and re-importing google-json file from firebase. The main problem I found that after updating the android studio the sha-1 or md5 code has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file replace 'compile' with 'implementation' and sync project.
Thank me later.

Comment: This should a comment

Comment: Nope, @Istiak. Albeit short, it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue for a newly created android project in Android studio Arctic Fox
Change "testImplementation", "androidTestImplementation" for all test dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

*Couldn't parse the android application module Gradle config*
then there must be some problem in your grade build,
In my case, I imported an old project which wasn't using android X, so I migrate to android X, and in the process, you will have to add these lines of code too in **gradle.properties** file,

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

- I had changed to android x but not set these to true that why I was getting error
  you can learn more about migrating to android X from here,

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing :

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

I hope this works!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem but at least I managed to resolve it and the Best Way:

Please Make Changes in Application Module's Gradle config:

In Android: compileSdk 31 ---Change Your SDK Version Like in My Project I use 31

After compileOptions{} you add this :

compileSdkVersion 31 ---Add this code in your buildToolsVersion '30.0.3' ---Add this code in your

In dependencies add this:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2' ---Change Your dependencies

Now Sync Your Project Firebase Console will be open……

Video Link:
https://youtu.be/trQtxMbMLFk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After 12 hours searching and attemp, I finally found some the possible reasons for this problem.

1. your gradle version is too high, lower it down to 7.0.0 and 7.0.4
2. try to change your sdk version to 30 or 31
3. if it is still not working, use binary check method to test all your dependencies

***If the firebase connected button is green but you still cannot setValue:***

1. check your avd to ensure it contains google play service, not google apis
2. check your avd to have enough storage to run google play, the default 512mb is not enough sometimes of your app is quite large.

Answer (score -1):

the solution is already provided by many. but interestingly the location of the issue was different in my case. commenting out **jcenter()** in the **settings.gradle** files solved the issue for me.