# Error Firebase Configuration in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync 
I am getting this message while connecting to firebase from android studio

[image]

Comment: paste your gradle app file

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to **depreciation** of the Compile keyword in built.gradle(app level)

```
      WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018.
```

Its Solution is to

1. Just replace the **compile** keyword with **implementation** or **api** in built.gradle(app level)

   **&**
2. Rebuilt your project

Restart your Android Studio if not Solved after Rebuilt.

Comment: @ Sheharyar Ejaz actually my error with extra implementation added in gradle and i removed it then its work.

Answer (score 0):

I bump into similar issues and found the following entry in my project’s `build.gradle` to be the culprit. I am not sure why or what other libraries are affected.

```
// Firebase Assistant - Connect to Firebase hate this library
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/how-to-add-firebase-to-android/#gradle-config-parsing-error

Another suggestion is gzip files in your project might be the culprit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40577173/561259