# Error: Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I've been trying to setup Firebase in my Android project.
Problem is, I've been getting this error:

> Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config

And I really can't solve it.

I've seen quite a lot of people getting this error, but it seems that they could solve it by upgrading their build tool version, or by updating google-services. I've done all that and haven't been able to make it work so far.

Here are my Gradle scripts:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    AndroidAppPro {
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.critizr.pro"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.5.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    preprod {
        applicationId "com.cr.pro"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PROD', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://myurl.com/"'
    }
    prod {
        applicationId "com.cr.pro"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_PROD', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://myurl/"'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
     exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
     exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
   }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':lib-viewflow')

// new libs
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1'

compile 'com.joshdholtz.sentry:sentry-android:1.5.0'
compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.6'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-core:1.2.2'
compile 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android:1.2.2'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the second one:

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880092/error-firebase-configuration-in-android-studio

Answer (score 31):

For me by ***removing*** the warning of jCenter ***worked***

```
jCenter()  remove it..
```

Comment: Don't know why google would do this. They could have taken care to not show this jCenter in the hello world android projects at least.

Comment: What is this? How do you remove it?

Comment: Just comment out the line..

Answer (score 23):

To solve this on **Android Studio v3.1** (not sure about previous versions), just edit your app's *build.gradle* like this:

- **Look for**:
  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and **remove it** then sync. Now you'll be able to use the Firebase Assistant with no issues.

Comment: This answer is correct but poorly explained. Actually the reason why this error occurred it's because u added admob app to ur app before connecting, you need to remove aply pluging inorder ro restart again. Remember no need to remove any other dependenciess or json file

Comment: It solved the problem thanks, @KarueBensonKarue thanks for your explanation as well.

Comment: update the same to latest version, worked for me. Android studio 4.3

Answer (score 22):

Verify the **build tab**, and make sure you've got no warnings in there.

Firebase Assistant seems to be very sensitive to **any** Gradle info, warning, or error.

For me it was a simple "info" from gradle, that `databinding.enabled` is not required anymore:

```
 DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.
```

Once removed, Firebase Assistant worked fine.

Comment: I have one of my dependency, android studio was complaining on. As soon as I deleted that dependency, voila.
So, checking the build tab was the solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The Navigation Component's safeargs plugin can also cause this. To fix it, I temporarily removed `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'` from app-level `build.gradle` file and then added it back in afterwards.

Comment: worked for me! But what could be the possible reason behind this ?

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Commenting out `apply plugin: io.fabric` worked for me. So check your dependencies in your gradle file.

Answer (score 5):

I think some of your dependencies are behind  it . Just go to your build.gradle (module app) and comment out most of them or all of them (to find out which one) , sync again ignore all error for now and try connecting to firebase again  if it's successful then you can go back to your build.gradle and uncomment them to fix errors.

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked for me, I think the culprit was `apply plugin: io.fabric` or `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem for `viewBinding`. Did as in the instructions from Google and it all worked.

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Comment: Addition of this code helped.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was the jcenter Repository, because it is deprecated since  March 31st 2021, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration

I replaced `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`. Now it works.

Comment: The default android project still shows jCenter even though the Google developers know it's deprecated

Answer (score 3):

change the gradle build tool version to 3.0.1

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs due to **depreciation** of the Compile keyword in built.gradle(app level)

```
      WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018.
```

Its Solution is to

1. Just replace the **compile** keyword with **implementation** or **api** in built.gradle(app level)

   **&**
2. Rebuilt your project

Restart your Android Studio if not Solved after Rebuilt.

Answer (score 3):

## Conclusion

The real culprit is the warnings of your `build.gradle`. Firebase assistant is very sensitive, it checks for any warning (even deprecated one) in your `build.gradle` & then starts working. If it finds any, then you will get this error.

## Solution

Just remove or resolve every warning of the `build.gradle` file. also, remove plugins that already exist of the same thing you are adding.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all previous Firebase dependencies in your project and try again. Plugins and libraries.

I had this issue before because I had already setup Firebase manually.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I do this? I am facing the same issue and I had setup Firebase manually time ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not use databinding remove from your app level gradle

```
 dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Remove these lines from your app level gradle

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused because I used data binding in my project. Here is how I fixed the issue:

In your build.gradle(App level) set the dataBinding as follow:

Put this code in your build.gradle(Project level) under the buildTypes:

```
//Here is the code...
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Follow the solution step by step.

**1. In Gradle Script/build.gradle(Project:your project name):**

Add dependencies

```
dependencies {  
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
 
}
    }
```

jcenter remove or do comment out:

```
   allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
           // jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
```

**2. In Gradle Script/gradle.properties:**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**3. In Gradle Script/build.gradle(:app):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

before build types add buildFeatures:

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

at the last:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

**4. Add google servises json file**

location:
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Whatsup_project\app

See the [youtube video](https://youtu.be/s6R5VAH1ySg) on how to add a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

Remove following from Gradle

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
```

This worked for me and also connected to Firebase without any issue, you just need to rebuild project and then click on connect to firebase. It's done.

Comment: This worked :)! Buggy Android

Answer (score 1):

In my case most of the dependencies were included with `compile` rather than `implementation`. So converting `compile` to `implementation` in my `build.gradle(Module : app)` worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

in case of flutter project after commenting this line worked for me

```
//apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Comment: And also comment these lines:
`
//def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
//if (flutterRoot == null) {
//    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
//}

`
and

`
//flutter {
//    source '../..'
//}
`

Answer (score 1):

To enable google firebase services in your app you need to add [google services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) to your gradle file(`build.gradle`). so in the gradle file
under dependencies add :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'  // Google Services plugin
```

under repositories check that you have Google's Maven repository as

```
google() //Google's Maven repository
```

For detailed breakdown on how to set up firebase [check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After very long trying many things.
this solved me : changing google services version to 4.2.0 in build gradle
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

now my build gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing this problem I have simply removed 20.0.1 from,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
```

(**NOTE: I have implemented firebase-boM first so it has occurred in my case.**)

Then synced and tried reconnecting then it was successful.
I think it occurs for many reasons.
If you are using firebase boM. then don't specify any other firebase dependencies versions. after successful sync, it should be solved.
In your case, I can not declear why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to remove all the gradle warning before doing this. In my case, I used `buildFeatures { viewBinding true}`

instead of
`buildFeatures { dataBinding true }`

Comment: Whats the difference in the two declarations you mentioned here?

Comment: Sorry for my  mistake, I have made it correct now . Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1):

What solved my issue was:
deleting

`databinding{enabled = true}`

and inserting

`buildFeatures{dataBinding = true}`

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem and I found the best way to solve this problem is: connect your Application manually to the firebase database.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue. I had to delete `useProguard` from the `buildTypes` in your app gradle.

After that I did not get the warning any more

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change minSdkVersion in build.gradle(Module: app) file to 25 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i update the minSdkVersion in build.gradle to the last one 28.0.3 and after i sync it work fine

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

Go to Gradle.properties in your android

Disable `android.enableR8=true` by adding a `#` in front:

```
#android.enableR8=true
```

Alternatively, you can swap out the R8 for D8, The build system changed to using D8 instead of R8.

```
android.enableD8=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the versions to below.

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.1.3 and the Gradle Version to 6.5 in Project Structure. It helped me and it might help you too. [Android Firebase: Could not parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444180/android-firebase-could-not-parse)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have no same build tools version for your project level. If no download and restart IDE. again build both two gradles and after that run the project. Remember to run the project 1 time at least before using Firebase assist.

Answer (score 0):

Mine solved with removing jcenter() in Project level gradle . It may be happens when some weird dependency or some other plugins are added in project . Here jcenter() is showing - jcenter will die soon . So after deleting it and resync project , Connect to firebase option worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced this in my **app/build.gradle**

```kotlin
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

to this:

```kotlin
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

and now I can connect my App to Firebase

Comment: can you  please tell me where you put this like in which place in the Gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

With me!! **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)**

Im only changer this: **In**

> build.gradle (:app)

To

```
android {
compileSdk 29 //29 -> 31(new version SDK)

defaultConfig {
...
}
```

and ***Sync*** done.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:-

1. Changed Gradle version to 7.3.3
2. Changed CompiledSdk and TargetSdk to 31

Answer (score 0):

I just changed target sdk version 32 to 31. and it works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you fixed everything in the gradle files, then check your Manifest file. Sometimes the manifest file will affect your application config file in terms of causing issues for Firebase integration.

Answer (score 0):

Updating gradle version as follows worked for me. None of the above helped. Previous was 4.2.2 and 6.7.1

[image]