# Error when connecting Firebase to Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, gradle

I am trying to learn how to create an Android application with Android Studio. My project is currently blank, the only page is `MainActivity.java`. I created a project in Firebase and put the name (`com.example.connect`), and I added the JSON file to the App location, but when I click connect, I get the following error:

> (Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync)

How can I fix it?

**Build Gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
rootProject.name = "RUVOLT"
include ':app'
```

**Build Gradle Module**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ruvolt"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279479/error-could-not-parse-the-android-application-modules-gradle-config)

Answer (score 4):

In your `build.gradle`, apply these plugins and libraries for adding firebase:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

In your class path file, please verify that you entered these lines properly inside the `dependencies` tag:

```html
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
```

**Also, make sure you have added the JSON file of Google under the `app` section of the project file. For proper reference, go to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase).**

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the Google service plugin:

   ```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    }
   ```
2. Also check the `build.gradle` project for the Google service dependency

   ```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
   ```