# Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I wanna use firebase database but when I clicked on "Connect to firebase" button,  I got this problem ....
can anyone help me???

```
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.
```

Comment: This solution works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742260/7705712

Answer (score 7):

This problem is connected with one or more of your plugins.

Paste this:

```
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

to your gradle.properties file.

Now make rebuld. You must see a stacktrace with the problem plugin.
Switch off this plugin, sync and try to connect to Firebase again - must be success now.

After successful connection to Firebase you can return your plugins, remove that line from the gradle.properties file and resync. Warning will appear again, but it is not important, because Firebase has configured already.

P.S. In my case I had 2 problem plugins: Sceneform and Crashlytics.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple in my case. I'd just changed my compileSdk 32 to compileSdk 31 in build.gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.grocerystore"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also having same problem but I Found The Solution Then
To Solve This problem

- Go To Gradle Scripts Folder
- Then open build.gradle(Project)
- Remove the line - "jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon"
- Click on Connect to Firebase
- It may ask to build so build the project
- Then again click on Connect to Firebase
- The you will be success full to open it

Answer (score 1):

My case was in the dependencies of `build.gradle(:app)`
it fixed when I tested commenting the line

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and found the following entry in my project’s build.gradle to be the source of issue:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/how-to-add-firebase-to-android/#gradle-config-parsing-error

Another possibility is that gzips in your project might be the culprits. Search it up within your project folder and delete them, let gradle re-sync it for you.

Possible alternative solutions: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/issues/13 https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/159

Comment: I tried all of them, but the problem didn't solve !!

Comment: what exactly "gzips" are??

Comment: is this file "google-services.json" maybe the culprit ??

Comment: gzip is compression format i.e files with .gz extension, try again by updating com.google.gms:google-services to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was to comment out `Fabric` plugin (`apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`) from the app level build.gradle. Then, connect to firebase using the Firebase assistant. After connection is successful, you can uncomment the fabric plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and in my case, I resolved it by reducing the **compileSdkVersion** from **34 to 33**. After making this adjustment, I clicked on 'Connect to Firebase,' and it worked.