# How to get more details about Firebase connect error?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am trying to connect to Firebase using Firebase assistant, however I get this error:

```
Connect to Firebase
Could not parse the Android Application
Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build
issues and/or resync.
```

[image]

The question is, how can I get more details about the error? as I already can build the project successfully.

I thought I can use the terminal in Android Studio to connect to Firebase to get more details about the error, but I could not find anyone doing so..

Any idea? is there a verbose mode for the assistant?

Comment: Try reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577122/android-app-does-not-connect-to-firebase

Comment: Yea, I already saw it, did not help though.. I need to see the error details..

Comment: Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068128/2075349