# API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I don't get from my stack trace who is calling `variant.getAssemble()`

Android Studio version: 3.4
Gradle version 5.1.1

Comment: try to run `gradlew clean`

Comment: might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I am not using fabric, as I said, I could not figure out from stacktrace what api is calling `variant.getAssemble()`

Comment: is it stopping the build ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy, no it is just a warning, but I cannot configure firebase  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191685/could-not-parse-the-android-application-modules-gradle-config ) and I understand that fixing that could solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Android Gradle* plugin utilizes [Task Providers](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) and deprecated all direct task accesses. One such direct access is `variant.getAssemble()`. From your stacktrace it seems that the ***Gradle Play Publisher*** plugin is calling this API, but since the current version of the plugin is not written in *Groovy* anymore and already uses `assembleProvider` you should really update it!