# Android Firebase: Could not parse

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I tried connecting Firebase with my app and this error came

[image]

This is my build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I tried checking for .gzips from this answer [Android app does not connect to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577122/android-app-does-not-connect-to-firebase/49808375) but didn't find any .gzips file

What to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the answer just a few minutes after I posted the question and I thought of deleting it but I'm keeping it since other people might run into this asking for an answer so here I go.

In File/Project Structure/Project, change the Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.1.3 and the Gradle Version to 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

> Just downgraded your Gradle plugin version.In File/Project Structure/Project, change the Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.2.2

[Here is the example it worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJaSp.png)

Comment: Yes, I did the same, I downgraded it lower.